# How to subset a pandas dataframe column by a single date in a datetime column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp, subset

So I thought this should have been a simpler task but I could not find it. I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
Company Id      DateTime               col1  col2       col3    col4   col5     col6
0   25502921    2018-08-16 10:23:36     0   175.000     0.0     0.0     0.0     0
1   25502921    2018-08-16 10:33:55     0   155.557     0.0     0.0     0.0     0
2   25502921    2018-08-16 10:43:55     0   153.615     0.0     0.0     0.0     0
```

`type(df['DateTime'][0])` outputs `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

How can i subset the dataframe based on a date?

`df_tmp = df[df['DateTime'].dt.date=='16-08-2018']` does not seem to work nor does `df_tmp = df[df['DateTime']=='16-08-2018']`

What are the other intuitive methods i can try?

Answer (score 1):

use `.dt.normalize()` which converts the time to `00:00:00` but returns a datetime object.

```
df['DateTime'].dt.normalize().apply(type)
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

---

```
print(df['DateTime'].dt.normalize())

0   2018-08-16
1   2018-08-16
2   2018-08-16
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
df[df['DateTime'].dt.normalize() == '2018-08-16']

   Company_Id            DateTime  col1     col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0    25502921 2018-08-16 10:23:36     0  175.000   0.0   0.0   0.0     0
1    25502921 2018-08-16 10:33:55     0  155.557   0.0   0.0   0.0     0
2    25502921 2018-08-16 10:43:55     0  153.615   0.0   0.0   0.0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll get better performance and easier processing when you set the DateTime as the index:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = '\s{2,}',parse_dates=['DateTime'])
df.set_index("DateTime").loc["2018-08-16"]
```